# Spring JPA Specification Where condition parenthesis

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-jpa

How can i use spring JPA Specification for where condition as below:

**Where cond1 and (cond2 or cond3)**

AND

**Where (cond1 and cond2) or cond3**.

Specification code is as below:

```
Specification<DocRecord> updatedAtAndCountGTZeroSpec = new Specification<DocRecord>() {

    @Override
    public Predicate toPredicate(Root<DocRecord> root, CriteriaQuery<?> query, CriteriaBuilder cb) {
        return cb.or(
            (cb.and(
                cb.lessThanOrEqualTo(root.get("updatedAt"),new Timestamp(now.getTimeInMillis())),
                cb.lessThan(root.get("attemptCount"), 3))
            ),
            (cb.equal(root.get("attemptCount"), 0))
        );
    }
};
```

Above is production where condition as below:

**where docrecord0_.updated_at < ? 
and docrecord0_.attempt_count<3 
or docrecord0_.attempt_count=0**

Comment: Well, you did the second one. What's the problem?

Comment: How to achieve first one. My main concern is for parenthesisation in Specification.

Comment: `cb.and(cond1, cb.or(cond2, cond3))`? Not sure I understand your issue...

Comment: In your second snippet, you have two conditions separated by `or`. So you start by `cb.or`. In your first snippet, the two main conditions are separated by and, so start by `cb.and`. I don't get what the difficulty is.

Comment: I have the same problem, the query generated should be :
where docrecord0_.updated_at < ? and (docrecord0_.attempt_count<3 or docrecord0_.attempt_count=0)
but what i get on console is :
where docrecord0_.updated_at < ? and docrecord0_.attempt_count<3 or docrecord0_.attempt_count=0
without any parenthesis

Answer (score 3):

You can build the 'OR' specification, then add an 'AND'  specification for the first one

```
Specification<?> spec = spec1.or(spec2);
spec = spec.and(spec3);
```

> spec is actually equal to (spec1 OR spec2) AND spec3